# Docker for Mac and --host option

Tags: mongodb, docker, protractor, docker-for-mac

I've been using Docker for Mac (Version 1.12.0-a (build: 11213)).

I'm trying to use an [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/webnicer/protractor-headless/) to run my Protractor tests.
I'm running the tests using this command:
`docker run -it --privileged --rm --net=host -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -v $(pwd):/protractor webnicer/protractor-headless src/test/e2e/config/docker-config.js`

This is my config file:

```
exports.config = {

  onPrepare: function() {
    global.nodeModulesPath = '../../main/webapp/node_modules/';
    global.mongoConnection = '127.0.0.1:27017';
    global.dbName = 'DB_name'; 

    var width = 1280;
    var height = 768;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
  },

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/my-app/',

  specs: ['../tests/**/*.spec.js'],

  restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    isVerbose: true,
    includeStackTrace: true
  }
};
```

Mongo is running inside a container and the `webnicer/protractor-headless` container can see Mongo and can insert all the data (I checked Mongo and confirmed via `docker logs`).

But looks like `webnicer/protractor-headless` cannot see the `localhost:8080` where the app is deployed.

Looks like this is related with the `--net=host` option, but I'm not sure. Anyone have an idea or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From the image page:

> Why --net=host?
>
> This options is required only if the dockerised Protractor is run
>   against localhost on the host. Imagine this sscenario: you run an http
>   test server on your local machine, let's say on port 8000. You type in
>   your browser http://localhost:8000 and everything goes smoothly. Then
>   you want to run the dockerised Protractor against the same
>   localhost:8000. If you don't use --net=host the container will receive
>   the bridged interface and its own loopback and so the localhost within
>   the container will refer to the container itself. Using --net=host you
>   allow the container to share host's network stack and properly refer
>   to the host when Protractor is run against localhost.

Comment: Yes. But I think this option is not stable when using Docker for Mac.